# Inline styles from jQuery removed afer ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm adding some inline styles on elements with jQuery, according to the user's actions.

On the same page I have some ajax calls and after ajax call all these inline styles is removed.

I need to remember all inline styles added through jQuery before ajax call and to apply them after ajaxComplete.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide some context? Without some code it will be hard to help...General answer - set styles variables, add them to ajax call, and get them on success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse all styles to object

```
$els.each(){
object[$el.attr('id')] = $el.attr('style') //get
..
for(var el in object){
$('#'+el).attr('style', object[el]) //set
...
```

You have a specific list of items?